React useState not initializing properly at re-render
I have a problem with React useState hook. I have a nested component that is inside of an array like this:
export default ParentComponent = () => {

  return (
    <>
      { someArray.map( (item, i) => {
         <ChildComponent key={i} someData={item} />
      }) }
    </>
  )

}

Now, the ChildComponent receives an object (standard JSON) with some values, for instance {firstName:'John', company:'The Office'}, so ChildComponent initializes like this:
export default ChildComponent = ({someData}) => {
   const [ dataInChild, updateData ] = useState(someData);

   return (
     <div>
       <input name="firstName" value={dataInChild.firstName} />
       <input name="company" value={dataInChild.company} />
     </div>
   )
}

It works fine if I edit the values on the input fields, I have no problem at all. I also have other methods to control the onChange and even onBlur, but that's not the issue.
The problem is when the parent deletes one element of the array. For instance, let's say the array has something like this:
[
 {firstName: "Steve", company: "The Office"},
 {firstName: "Gunther", company: "Central Perk"},
 {firstName: "Clark", company: "The Daily Planet"}
]

If I delete, say, the second element, the array is updated as:
[
 {firstName: "Steve", company: "The Office"},
 {firstName: "Clark", company: "The Daily Planet"}
]

Deleting the element is with a simple .splice() in the array. I have tested and debugged a few days now and the array does update as expected. However, when the component re-renders, I debugged and the useState hook does receive the updated data, but when running this line of code
const [ dataInChild, updateData ] = useState(someData);
//Debugging here right after calling useState, dataInChild has previous value

the variable someData does contain the updated element of the array but the variable dataInChild still keeps the original value. By that I mean that the array does render 2 elements instead of 3, but the second item is still Gunther, when it should be Clark.
Any thoughts?

Question 1 - why are you using index (i) as a key inside map function? It is an aptipattern and can lead to  bugs similar to what you have. Question 2 - how exactly are you splicing the array? Do you update the state with the copy of the spliced array after that to make react detect the changes and rerender ui with new data?

I make a copy of the array and then splice it. After that I use the function provided in the useState for the entire array in the Parent component. After that, the Child component is rendered for every loop and it receives the updated elements one by one. It's the useState inside the Child component that won't update the value for that element.

In that case you need to add a useEffect (inside ChildComponent) with someData in its dependency array and make this useEffect call updateData to actually update ChildComponent's  state. The useState you have will not track updates of someData, it will set the data from it only once during initial render.

Just tried that, but it's not entering the useEffect with someData in the dependency array. I think it's because the data in the child component is not being updated at all. The parent component is simply deleting it. However, I'm wondering about how the data is being kept after deletion. Could it be because the key in the parent component is the same as before? I mean, at position 1, the first time around is "Gunther" and that's the one still being rendered even after it's been eliminated.

I finally got it. Now I know what you mean by antipattern with the index as the key. If I use something different in each element, but that remains fixed for that particular element, it works as expected. Thanks for the tip.

using splice mutates the state and states should not be mutated. See this example

In your first code, you're using { <Component/> } in your map function, without returning anything. I'm pretty sure you meant to use parentheses () instead, or at least use a return
